R convert list output from loop to data frame
I have a series of numbers.
n <- c(10, 5, 35, 16, 2)
n <- as.data.frame(n)

I ran these numbers through a loop that randomly samples from -18 to 18 the number of times of the values, e.g., 10, 5.
p <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(n)) {
  p[[i]] <- sample(-18:18, n$n[i], replace = TRUE)
}

The output looks like this:
[[1]]
[1] 6 1

[[2]]
[1]  4  1 12 -8 -9

[[3]]
[1] -13 -18  18

[[4]]
[1] 17 -4  9 17

[[5]]
[1] -2 18

How do I convert this to a data frame that also has an ID variable corresponding to the order? I want the output to look like this:
CT  ID
6   1 
1   1
4   2
1   2
12  2
-8  2
-9  2
-13 3
-18 3
18  3
17  4
-4  4
9   4
17  4
-2  5
18  5

My actual data has around 300 variable cells/lists that need to be converted. I tried creating another loop, but keep encountering syntax errors.

If this question is representative of your actual problem, sampling n times by the number of rows is the same as taking one big sample if replace=TRUE. E.g. data.frame(ID = rep(seq_along(n$n), n$n), CT = sample(-18:18, sum(n$n), replace=TRUE)) - would that be okay?

If one call to sample (i.e. sum(n)) is not what you want, we can Vectorise sample() like
set.seed(1)
n = c(10, 5, 35, 16, 2)
data.frame(ID=rep(seq(n), n), 
           CT=unlist(Vectorize(sample, "size")(-18:18, n, TRUE)))

giving
   ID  CT
1   1 -15
2   1 -18
3   1  15
4   1   4
5   1  -5
6   1  -1
7   1  14
8   1   2
9   1   2
10  1  -9
11  2 -12
12  2 -10
13  2  -4
14  2   2
15  2  18
16  3   6
17  3  18
18  3  18
19  3  15
20  3   6
21  3  -4
22  3  14
23  3   1
24  3  16
25  3 -13
26  3  -9
27  3   1
28  3   9
29  3   1
30  3   4
31  3 -13
32  3   6
33  3 -13
34  3 -13
35  3   5
36  3  13
37  3  -5
38  3 -17
39  3  -1
40  3   3
41  3  -5
42  3 -18
43  3 -13
44  3   4
45  3 -13
46  3  -8
47  3  -2
48  3  17
49  3  -6
50  3   6
51  4   6
52  4   4
53  4   1
54  4  10
55  4  -6
56  4   3
57  4  10
58  4   9
59  4  14
60  4   2
61  4  12
62  4  -2
63  4 -10
64  4   4
65  4   0
66  4   7
67  5  11
68  5  13


n <- c(10, 5, 35, 16, 2)
s <- lapply(
  seq_along(n), 
  \(i) data.frame(CT = sample(-18:18, n[i], replace = TRUE), ID = i)
)
do.call(rbind.data.frame, s)

gives:

    CT ID
1    9  1
2  -15  1
3   10  1
4   10  1
5   -9  1
6   -3  1
7    3  1
8   18  1
9    2  1
10  15  1


Using tidyverse:
n <- c(10, 5, 35, 16, 2)
map(n, \(N) data.frame(CT = sample(-18:18, N, replace = TRUE))) |> 
  bind_rows(.id = 'ID')


Here are two other options

dplyr with enframe + unnest

n %>%
  map(sample, x = -18:18, replace = TRUE) %>%
  enframe() %>%
  unnest(value)

which gives
# A tibble: 68 × 2
    name value
   <int> <int>
 1     1   -15
 2     1   -18
 3     1    15
 4     1     4
 5     1    -5
 6     1    -1
 7     1    14
 8     1     2
 9     1     2
10     1    -9
# ℹ 58 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


base R with lapply + stack

stack(
  lapply(
    setNames(n,seq_along(n)),
    sample,
    x = -18:18,
    replace = TRUE
  )
)

which gives
   values ind
1     -15   1
2     -18   1
3      15   1
4       4   1
5      -5   1
6      -1   1
7      14   1
8       2   1
9       2   1
10     -9   1
11    -12   2
12    -10   2
13     -4   2
14      2   2
15     18   2
16      6   3
17     18   3
18     18   3
19     15   3
20      6   3
21     -4   3
22     14   3
23      1   3
24     16   3
25    -13   3
26     -9   3
27      1   3
28      9   3
29      1   3
30      4   3
31    -13   3
32      6   3
33    -13   3
34    -13   3
35      5   3
36     13   3
37     -5   3
38    -17   3
39     -1   3
40      3   3
41     -5   3
42    -18   3
43    -13   3
44      4   3
45    -13   3
46     -8   3
47     -2   3
48     17   3
49     -6   3
50      6   3
51      6   4
52      4   4
53      1   4
54     10   4
55     -6   4
56      3   4
57     10   4
58      9   4
59     14   4
60      2   4
61     12   4
62     -2   4
63    -10   4
64      4   4
65      0   4
66      7   4
67     11   5
68     13   5

Data
set.seed(1)
n <- c(10, 5, 35, 16, 2)

